Find the missing number in an array
Problem Statement:
Given an integer N and an array of size N-1 containing N-1 numbers between 1 to N. Find the number (between 1 and N), that is not present in the given array.
One of my mentors solved this problem in O(n2)
// Outer loop that runs from 1 to N:
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    // flag variable to check if an element exists
    int flag = 0;

    // Search the element using linear search:
    for (int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {
        if (a[j] == i) {
            // i is present in the array:
            flag = 1;
            break;
            }
        }

        // check if the element is missing
        // flag == 0:
        if (flag == 0) return i;
    }
}

My question is: Why can't we run the loop from 1 to N and compare the values of array?
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   if (a[i] != i + 1) {
      return i;
      break;
   }
}


This is related to https://leetcode.com/problems/missing-number/description/  and to https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/description/ . There are several questions and answers on StackOverflow related to these.

the last code snippet can be used if the array is sorted (and if you remove the break; - unreachable statement)

By the way, the problem statement is flawed. The word “between” means the gap or interval after the first boundary and before the last boundary. So if N were 10, “between 1 to N” means the eight integers of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. The problem should state explicitly whether the beginning and the ending are inclusive or exclusive. Other phrasing such as “from 1 to N” are also ambiguous.

The problem doesn't state that the array is sorted. With your solution, if the array is [2, 4, 1], it will return that 2 is missing, while the real missing element is 3.
Having said that, there is an O(n) solution to this problem with some math.
If there was no number missing, a series of numbers from 1 to N is an arithmetic progression, and we can easily calculate its expected sum. We can then iterate over the array and subtract each element we encounter. Once we're done subtracting all the elements that are present, the remainder will be the missing element:
private static int findMissing(int[] arr) {
    int n = arr.length + 1;
    int sum = (1 + n) * n / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        sum -= arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

Note: I used an int to calculate the sum, which should be fine for N values up to 65535. If N is larger than that, you may want to use a long, or even a BigInteger.

It's a well-known interview question. (One that I never use because I see it as a "Trick question" that has no room in an interview)
